# Want to redirect the output of the nohup command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, ksh

I am executing a shell script to Start a service.
Inside the script I am using nohup command to start the service but my output is being redirected to nohup.out file Any idea?
I am providing my code below

```
  #!/usr/bin/ksh
     echo "===========================================================================
 ==" | tee -a /opt/users/Feroz/tools_boot.log |echo $(date '+%d-%m-%y  %H:%M:%S') "Starting Weblogic services" | tee -a /opt/users/Feroz/tools_boot.log
     ##
     # Set up Working directory for Weblogic 
     #   
     cd /feroz/weblogic_apps/environment/bin
    echo $(date '+%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S') "Starting Weblogic services environment" |tee -a /opt/users/Feroz/tools_boot.log
     cmd="nohup ./startNodeManager.sh  >startNodeManager.out 2>&1 &"
     echo ^M |$cmd
     #sleep 10
     #cmd="nohup ./startWebLogic.sh >startWebLogic.out 2>&1 &"
     #echo ^M|$cmd 

     echo $(date '+%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S') "Weblogic services INT environment 
     Started" |tee -a /opt/users/Feroz/tools_boot.log

    echo "Successful"
```

Output

```
   19-05-17 02:37:59 Starting Weblogic service
   19-05-17 02:37:59 Starting Weblogic services environment
   nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
   19-05-17 02:38:02 Weblogic services environment Started
   Successful
```

Comment: Try something like below.
        
        nohup ./startNodeManager.sh >| startWebLogic.out 2>&1 &